# Why don't my .asmx service is accessible to others in the same network?

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-8.1

I have hosted my website which has .asmx webservice in IIS locally, it is accessible via IP address and webservice path in my local system but not from other systems on the same network.

```
http://192.168.1.111/DS/Adds.asmx
```

now this linked can be accessed on my computer but not on others in the same network.

Comment: Have you checked your firewall settings if the ports are accessible from outside?

Comment: FIrewall is off and port is binded to 80

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specifically allow incoming connections to your application. Start `cmd.exe` as administrator and run this command:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://192.168.1.111:80/ user=everyone
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code to your web.config file under system.web section:

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet" />
    <add name="HttpPost" />
    <add name="HttpSoap12" />
    <add name="HttpSoap" />
  </protocols>
</webServices>
```